# VPN with Tor and SSH - is it secure & what caveats should I know about?

Tags: privacy, vpn, tor

I am doing research on web security and anonymizing strategies. So, far, I know what a VPN is, how Tor works and how SSH works.

But, I am trying to understand the caveats or possible compromises in the following scenario:

1. I connect to a VPN
2. From there I connect to Tor
3. Finally I ssh into a remote Linux box - that is not tied to my real identity.

What are the pitfalls? How can I be traced? If this is untraceable, why are more people not using it already? Am I missing something?